# Mi ciclo for no funciona

Tags: c, bucle-for

En lenguaje C estoy intentando que mi ciclo For haga una iteración desde 0 hasta el valor de "poroto" y que cada vez que itere imprima la linea 15 de "ingrese su valor" pero cuando compilo me salta me ignora el primer for, y pasa al segundo. Alguna idea de que estare haciendo mal? estoy aprendiendo perdon haha

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int proto;
    printf("Ingrese un numero para definir el tamaño del array: \n");
    scanf("%d\n",&proto);
    
    int arr[proto];
    
    for(int i=0; i < proto; i++)
    {
        printf("Ingrese su valor %d\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d\n", &arr[i]);
    }
    
    printf("El valor del array es: \n");
    for(int i=0; i < proto; i++)
    {
        printf("Usted ingreso el numero en la posicion %d\n", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código va como texto, edita tu pregunta por favor.

Comment: en C no puedes crear arreglos de forma dinámica de esa forma, tienes que utilizar la función```int* PortaPorotos = malloc(sizeof(int)*poroto);```

Comment: @VictorJimenez99 De hecho, en ISO C99 sí se puede [doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/gcc/Variable-Length.html). El arreglo es guardado en la stack y se elimina cuando se termina su scope

Comment: Quita los `\n` de tus `scanf()`

Answer (score -1):

Tu for está bien planteado y puede funcionar perfectamente per tienes primero que declarar la variable i. En c es obligatorio.

También estoy viendo que deberías añadir la librería `<locale.h>` y al principio de tu codigo poner `set_locale(LC_ALL,"spanish");` para que te deje poner tildes y eñes.